# Android Pop up with grid view

Tags: android

It is possible to create a pop up with grid View . for example I'm going to click a button and there is a pop up with grid view and I click one of the item it transfer to my image view and I tried many tutorial and not one of them suits for me. I'm new in android development please help or any advice or a sample snippets will do thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an activity with dialog theme and no title with your grid, then in you main activity do a startActivityForResult to this new "pop up" activity,

If you dont know how to put dialog theme, no title request or how to control activities for result let me know and I'll expand the answer

Declaration of the activity on the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".GridActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

With that the activity would look somewhat like a pop up. Use the XML you want for the layout, in your case I think you would use a gridView

When you need the pop up to show, you should call your activity. For example, you will call the pop up when calling a button:

```
public static final int GRID_REQUEST = 1; 

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GridActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,GRID_REQUEST);
}
```

With that, you launch an activity with a code. You will need that code to identify the activity when it is returned.

In GridActivity, when you finish doing your things, you have to close it giving a result. I think you need to give the path of an image, so I will do this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("imagePath", selectedImagePath);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

That would close the pop up and send back the selected image path to the previous activity. To receive the data, you need to override `onActivityResult` in your main activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == GRID_REQUEST) {
  if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
     String selectedImagePath =data.getStringExtra("imagePath");          
     //TODO: Set the image in your imageview
   }
   if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
     showError("The selection was cancelled");
   }
 }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: OK you have a snippets about it if you have I really appreciate it ..and thanks because I keep researching about it and doing some tutorial base on my issue ..

Comment: If you need any explanation tell me ;)

Comment: the GridActivity.class is an a java file right? where I papulate my grid view right?

Comment: and with the images i just put it in my drawable

Comment: Yes, GridActivity.class is a java class extending Activity, just like your other activities, where you populate your grid view, right

Comment: so how do i call the item that i selected by ID ?

Comment: You should get his ID, path or something that makes him identifiable in the gridActivity, then returnIntent.putExtra("imagePath", selectedImagePath); returning that identifier and recovering it and using it in the onActivityResult method of your main activity

Comment: in showing my picture going to make an int array for pictures right? so as you said im going to use an intent to show my selected item in my image view?

Comment: Im not sure I understand you. How are you showing your pictures in the GridActivity?

Comment: as what i research make an array some thing like this : ublic static int[] moodpic = {
   R.drawable.mode1, R.drawable.mode2, 
   R.drawable.mode3, R.drawable.mode4, 
   R.drawable.mode5, R.drawable.mode6,
   R.drawable.mode7, R.drawable.mode8
  };

Comment: ok, then when you selecte one, you should return that integer, returnIntent.putExtra("imageID", selectedImageID); being selectedImageId one of those. Then in onActivityResult, you should do int selectedImageID =data.getIntExtra("imageID"); imageView.setImageResource(selectedImageID);

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. For my opinion the easiest way is to create Subclass of DialogFragment with layout you want

dialog will look like this

```
public class GridDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

GridView mGridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // it title is not needed

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_dialog, container); // you should define dialog layout in resources

            mGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid);

            //initialize your gridview

            // ...
            return view;

       }

       //here can be other methods 

}
```

Your layout can look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_mainstyle"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- here can be other elements -->

    <GridView
     android:id="@+id/grid"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <!-- here can be other elements -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Than you can show dialog in the next way:

```
GridDialogFragment fr = new GridDialogFragment();
fr.setTitle(file.getName()); //Set title if needed

fr.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Do not forget to add support library to your project if your min sdk level less than 11

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  I'll give you ideas - but you'll need to do the work.

There are two ways to approach it - a custom dialog layout and an activity that looks like a dialog.

To create a custom dialog, create a DialogFragment with your custom layout, populate your gridview and set item click listeners.

To use a dialog-like activity, create an activity with a Dialog theme and no title bar, create whatever layout you like in it and add your onitemclick listeners.  Then from the main activity, use `startActivityForResult` to invoke this activity; from your itemclicklistener, use `setResult` and `finish` - then in the main activity use `onActivityResult` method to check which element was selected.

Start the work, write some code - if you have specific issues, post back with your code and details of what's not working and why.